# C++ tuples: time complexity for get(i)

Tags: c++, stl, tuples

I want to access element at position i of a tuple(https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/get)  in c++ .\
If for instance I have :\

```cpp
std::tuple <int, int, int> t{1, 2, 3};
int x = std::get<2>(t);
```

Is it constant time to access an element or linear?

Comment: It is constant time.

Comment: Everything is done during compile time. It should be same if you address the nth int inside a tuple as you access some other int somewhere.

Comment: @Klaus Not really, there's still some (not much, admittedly, but still) runtime-work being done here. It's specifically more akin to accessing an arbitrary member of a struct than "some other `int` somewhere".

Comment: Since a `tuple` is of a constant size, it would still qualify as constant even if a “linear” traversal over the `tuple` was needed. And it is **not** needed; the compiler will instead pre-compute the offset(s) of the elements at compile time. But no matter what, it’s always constant, because even 3 × constant == constant.

Comment: @AndrejPodzimek if it only has 3 elements for sure it's constant.. but my question was general : if it has more elements, assuming linear access, if I call many many times get, I could have an O(n^2) just for that..and I wanted to know if that's the case

Comment: @brucebanner In *theory*, `std::get()` does not have time guarantees attached to it. In *practice*, however, any implementation that does not do it in `O(1)` would be deemed unacceptable.

Comment: n² at compile time is still a constant for any n. But sure, understood, you wanted to know if e.g. a tuple with 10000 elements takes ~10000 steps of some sort to get the last element. To which the answer is *no*, access to the 0th as well as 9999th element takes roughly the same (small) constant number of steps and offsets are pre-computed at compile time. But it does take the compiler those 10000 steps at compile time, that’s for sure.

Comment: Also, you can build it with `-S` and look at the element accesses in assembler. It will probably involve a reference to the tuple and an offset stored as an “immediate” value. No cycles or other repeated steps.

Answer (score 0):

The two following blocks of code are functionally equivalent:

```
std::tuple<int, int, int> t{1, 2, 3};
int x = std::get<2>(t);
```

```
using __type_for_tuple_iii = struct {int __1; int __2; int __3;};
__type_for_tuple_iii t{1, 2, 3};
int x = t.__2;
```

**N.B.** This remains true no matter how many members the tuple has.

As you can see, `std::get<>(std::tuple)` doesn't really do much actual "work" per-se. More specifically, almost all of the work it does is guaranteed to be feasible during compilation. All that's left at runtime is a simple memory offset.

So you might as well be asking: "What is the complexity of accessing a struct's member?".

That answer to which is: **O(1)**, no matter how big the struct is, so the same goes for tuples and `std::get<>`.